# Reducing HDD seek time in reading the contents of many files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, files, hard-disk, php

I read millions of files in subdirectories of `/XX/XX/XX/` to process the content of each file. In PHP, I read the files as

```
foreach(glob("/folder/*") as $a){
  foreach(glob("$a/*") as $b){
    foreach(glob("$b/*") as $c){
      foreach(glob("$c/*") as $file){
      // Processing
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that this code fetches the files in a specific order, but I just need to read all files in any possible order (with the least seek time).

Is there a way to read the files in somehow sequential order (as stored on the HDD sectors) to reduce the seek time?

PHP code was to show how I ended up here, and do not expect to find a solution in PHP. My question is indeed about a solution in `shell`.

**UPDATE:**

I was not clear in describing the problem. I already have the full list of the files. The problem is not finding them, but the best order of reading their contents to reduce the seek time.

I tried to use `glob` instead of

```
foreach($files as $file){
  $content=file_get_contents($file);
}
```

with the hope to reduce the seek time for each file.

As I said before, language is not important. I can re-write the entire code in bash or C.

I re-phrase my question: ***What is the fastest way to read the contents of a few million files stored in nested folders (HDD with ext4)?***

Comment: I also very much doubt that sorting is the problem here: it's the approach of the program to rely on globbing to iterate through directories. Plainly put, the wrong tool.

Comment: I suggest to delete the question and ask a new concrete question.

Comment: Assumption: Reading in disk storage order is fastest. Use `hdparm --fibmap /path/to/file`, extract first block ID and sort accordingly. Assumption 2: If there is not much file fluctuation, sorting by inodes might be sufficient and simpler=faster (use `find` with `-printf '%i %h/%f\0'` or so). Assumption 3: getting and processing this sorting might eat up the time it saves - depending on size, number and fragmentation of the files.

Comment: @Cyrus good suggestion, but a question with answers cannot be deleted!

Comment: @Googlebot then simply ask the new question, remove your update here, and inform all the answerers in this question that you did; you've basically done a 180° turn with your question from being about shells to being about fast file access, and these things simply don't go together. Shells and PHP are both alike not able to to the things you need to do to minimize the amount of seek time (which is using asynchronous file descriptor interfaces, and most likely multiple threads fed from kernel waitlists)

Comment: @MarcusMüller there is no 180°-turn. My original question is pretty much the same as the update. I just clarified that my problem is not the fast finding, but fast reading the files.

Comment: no it's really a complete different problem. Your original question was "How do I make a shell script to read files in a specific order", now you say "What is the fastest way to read the contents of a few million files stored in nested folders (HDD with ext4)?" and the answer is 1. by not reordering. 2. by definitely not using the shell.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Quite the opposite. I said `glob` in my PHP code finds in a specific order. I look for a shell solution to find files in *no specific* order to reduce the seek time. By sequential order on the HDD, I was referring to the blocks of storage. After reading file #555, read any file which is close not file #556 according to `glob`. And why not in shell? There are more programs available in shell (as compared with PHP) for finding files.

Comment: I explained why not in shell, here in my comments and in my answer. Voting to close this as too broad; your original question was about shell programming, now you literally say you need it as fast as possible (which rules out shell), and can implement in any language. Let me know when you moved out the different question to a new question post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest `find`

```
find /folder/ -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f
```

It then depends how your processing is done whether you prefer to use `-exec`, `-execdir` or `-print0 | xargs -0`.

`find` is AFAIK one of the fastest methods to retrieve files.

Comment: As I updated the question, my problem is not getting the list of files (I already have it). The problem is the order of reading the contents of the files.

Comment: @Googlebot IF and only IF your directories and files are more or less filling chronologically (e.g. like dirs are YY/MM/DD and files HHMMSS; in contrast to randomly adding a file here and there in each subdir), then the inodes are more or less in the same order as the data on the disk and find goes by inodes in its sorting.

Answer (score 2):

"HDD sectors" don't matter here; the way folder contents are stored and accessed has little to do with the block structure of your storage device (depends on your filesystem, though).

Your PHP code is rather inefficient (which I'd blame PHP for – PHP's standard library makes writing efficient code very hard) and also not correct – if there's anything deeper than 4 layers of folders (you actually need to write something *recursing* through directories, and that's not how you do it).

Anyway, in `bash` this is very easy:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/** ; do
  echo "${file} found!"
done
```

However, this really doesn't help you if you need that list of files in PHP. You don't need globbing to walk through directories - in fact, that's plainly the wrong tool. Use PHP's methods to list directories, and whenever you find a directory, call the same method on the directory you've just found.

Comment: As I updated the question, the problem is not finding a solution in PHP. I can re-write the entire code in bash or any other language if I can read the contents of the files faster.

Comment: ""HDD sectors" don't matter here" -- why do you think so? On rotating disks, seek times aren't insignificant so avoiding or minimizing seeks would at least appear to influence the total time required to read the whole directory tree. A program reading the tree using synchronous system calls can't really even queue multiple requests at the same time (to let the kernel reorder them), since the data has to be fetched before the `read()` call can return, which must happen before the program can issue the next one...

Answer (score 1):

As a computer programmer since 1967, I remember when the ordering of files on the tiny, slow, mechanically positioned disks connected to small, slow computers was a concern. Progress has eliminated this concern. Faster, bigger computers, faster, bigger software (buffering in RAM makes disks approach RAM speed), faster, bigger, smarter disks and disk-like objects, and the further development of disk drivers, ... It's rare to be concerned with a file's actual position on disk, in the C/H/S sense. "Modern" disk drivers reorder requests to minimize seek time, and have done so for decades.

Generating your list of filenames is tricky. You don't need all million names at the beginning.

Use `find` (Read `man find` repeatedly), or roll your own directory traversal code.

A "directory" is a file with the `d------` bit set in its permissions.
It contains pointers to files or directories.

Any reasonable programming language will let you access the `readdir` interface (`man readdir`).

Comment: Thanks for the background. The problem is not finding the files or reading the directories. I already have the full paths of all files. The point is that how can I sort the files to read them in sequential order (somewhat) as opposed to random reads. `find` or `readdir` can help if finding the files in such order to reduce the seek time (or less jumps of the mechanical parts of the HDD to read each file).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to read millions of files is not to try to second-guess how the kernel does things internally (even if you did manage to do that correctly, a new kernel version may change things and then your code will experience a drop in performance), but to accept that you don't know and to ask the kernel multiple things at once; e.g., using multiple threads, multiple processes, or something like [libaio](https://pagure.io/libaio).

This way, if the kernel needs to wait because of seek times, it may be able to handle another request first for which the seek time is not as bad.

Answer (score 1):

> I re-phrase my question: What is the fastest way to read the contents of a few million files stored in nested folders (HDD with ext4)?

There's no better order than taking it in the order your file system offers them to you.

> files in somehow sequential order (as stored on the HDD sectors)

You're assuming files are somehow "ordered" on the disk, and it has something to do with the paths. **That's not the case, at all.**

A file system, and especially ext2/3/4, has an on-disk layout containing descriptions of files (and directories here are really just a bit special files pointing to lists of other files), and these descriptions encompass things like file names, and a list of blocks/extents which store the data in the file (if the file is not short enough to fit in with the metadata).

Now, these files typically are **not** contiguous on-disk if their paths are somehow related. That simply doesn't happen: Free space for new file data is chosen where available. Also, a single file in itself has no way of being guaranteed to be contiguous! The blocks storing the data don't have to be one after the other.

So, you really *can't* make this any faster from a userland perspective: The point of using a file system is to hide the fact that it's all blocks on a storage medium from the program using the file.

Best you can do is *not* to reorder the files. Chances (no guarantees!) are the order you're getting them from the file system when interacting using the `readdir` system call (no matter which programming language, there's one way to ask the file system for a list of files) is the same as the order of creation, which might be the order of space allocation, which might be the order of block-to-inode-mapping, and that might be somewhat corresponding to order on disk.

More importantly, you're fundamentally limited by the fact that you're trying to do something seek-time intense on a HDD (don't if you have access to SSDs) in a single thread with a file system not optimized for this kind of access (you'll *not* find a good classical file system for this, because it's not what classical file systems need to be good at).

So, architecturally, you can improve your approach (and that's what I meant when I said your PHP code was inefficient: it really is).

1. read the file contents as you discover the files, not later on: The metadata is just as distributed across your disk as your file data is, so jumping somewhere else to read a directory's file list has a seek time just as reading file contents. So, instead of "getting the list of files, then reading each file", do

   1. get the first entry in the directory
   2. if it's a file, initiate reading it 
      (that means

      - `open`ing it,
      - adding the file descriptor to a queue,
      - in a separate thread reading the queue,
      - there, track how many files are currently being worked through, and
      - if its below some sensible threshold, pop the tip of the queue,
      - `fadvise` that you want to read the whole file,
      - add the file descriptor to an `epoll` event, and
      - in another separate threat handling the epoll events using `epoll_wait`.

   Never let the disk get idle. Give the kernel a chance to make most use of its buffers, so that if you never have to seek twice to the same place on disk).
   If it's a directory, go to 1 on that directory

   3. Move on to the next directory.
2. make sure your file system buffers are large enough. You want all your filesystem metadata to be cacheable. On modern Linux systems, you don't have to do much but supply enough RAM.
3. avoid languages like PHP like the plague (they make it really hard to know which system calls are done beneath, and when a system call might lead to you seeking completely elsewhere, then that's your nr. 1 performance issue) (also, avoid PHP like the plague, it's a paragon of bad language design, as your snippet quite beautifully illustrates!)
4. if you need to do this more than once, consider simply `cp -ar` your data to a new file system (and maybe not [ext4](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-50-filesystems&num=3), but something working well for FS Mark and other synthetic "handle many files" problems), as that would make the directory entries be in creation (copy) order, and then the order of your file names actually is more likely to have something to do with your on-disk storage. Still, no guarantees!
   If this is read-only, there's ways of guaranteeing you get a specific order: put them into a read-only file system (I like squashfs, which can compress as well, which might *really* make more difference than you think). Put that file system raw on a disk, not inside some other file system!
5. Consider whether you really need file access– is a file system really the correct way of storing the info you have, or is it maybe a relational database (sqlite? Postgresql?) or some document-oriented database?